# Run certain .NET Core health checks depending on tags

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, health-check

I added .NET Core Health Checks to my app.

I want to use tags to only run one check if it's a basic check or all checks for a more detailed check.

This is what I've got:

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
                        .AddCheck("Check1", () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy("Service Is Healthy!"), tags: new[] { "basic", "full" })
                        .AddCheck<CheckLogsAreHealthy>("Check2", tags: new[] { "full" })
                        .AddCheck<CheckLvcConnectionStatus>("Check3", tags: new[] { "full" })
```

I thought my URL should look like this:

```
http://localhost:4000/api/health?tags=basic
```

or

```
http://localhost:4000/api/health?tags=full
```

But this does not seem to be the case. How do I run each check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be a late answer and I hope you already found your solution, but calling `AddHealthChecks` does not automatically create a URL for your health checks, it is only registering them.

To create an endpoint for your health checks, you have to call the `MapHealthChecks` method on `IEndpointRouteBuilder`. This method also accepts options with a `Predicate` field where you can pass a predicate to filter the health checks to execute. For example, the following example filters the registered health checks based on the tags and creates a `/health/basic` and a `/health/full` endpoints, each one executing the health checks having `basic` or `full` in their tags.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
...
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {      
      endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/basic", new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckOptions
      {
         Predicate = registration => registration.Tags.Contains("basic")
      });
      
      endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/full", new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckOptions
      {
         Predicate = registration => registration.Tags.Contains("full")
      });
   });
...
}
```

Comment: Hi, @ArnaudLeclerc,   In case any of the check fails from full category, how can we know which one was?